# Hierarchical queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a table with a structure like (id, parent_id) in Oracle11g.

```
id    parent_id
---------------
1     (null)
2     (null)
3     1
4     3
5     3
6     2
7     2
```

I'd like to query it to get all the lines that are hierarchically linked to each of these id, so the results should be :

```
root_id  id    parent_id
------------------------
1        3     1
1        4     3
1        5     3
2        6     2
2        7     2
3        4     3
3        5     3
```

I've been struggling with the `connect by` and `start with` for quite some time now, and all i can get is a fraction of the results i want with queries like :

```
select connect_by_root(id) root_id, id, parent_id from my-table
start with id=1
connect by prior id = parent_id
```

I'd like to not use any `for` loop to get my complete results.

Any Idea ?

Best regards,
Jérôme Lefrère

PS : edited after first answer, noticing me i had forgotten some of the results i want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted is missing the `from` clause and left an underscore out of `connect_by_root`, but I'll assume those aren't actually the source of your problem.

The following query gives you the result you're looking for:

```
select * from (
   select connect_by_root(id) root_id, id, parent_id
   from test1
   start with parent_id is null
   connect by prior id = parent_id)
where root_id <> id
```

The central problem is that you were specifying a specific value to start from, rather that specifying a way to identify the root rows. Changing `id = 1` to `parent_id is null` allows the entire contents of the table to be returned.

I also added the outer query to filter the root rows out of the result set, which wasn't mentioned in your question, but was shown in your desired result.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da2e9/6)

---

Comment Response:

In the version provided, you do get descendants of `id = 3`, but not in such a way that `3` is the root. This is because we're starting at the absolute root. Resolving this is easy, just omit the `start with` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT connect_by_root(id) root_id,
          id,
          parent_id
   FROM test1
CONNECT BY
   PRIOR id = parent_id)
WHERE root_id <> id
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da2e9/9)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my post so the `from` and missing underscore are not a problem anymore. Your query gets me the absolute roots. I'd like to get also the descendants of the `id=3` line

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
select connect_by_root(id) root_id, id, parent_id
from your_table
start with parent_id is null
connect by prior id = parent_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which was perfect until I noticed that I forgot some of the results i want : i want also the lines that are not absolute roots (see the last 2 results of my original post)

Comment: then just remove the `start with parent_id is null` part

Comment: It seems to work. Just need to check this on my more complex table to be sure

Answer (score 0):

It will give you the exact result you want:

```
select connect_by_root(id) as root, id, parent_id
from test1
connect by prior id=parent_id
start with parent_id is not null;
```