# Recursive relationship in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which stores the customer , related customer  and count of related customers.
The related customer can have again further related customers it's like a recursive relationships.

I wanted to find out all the related customers ( till the last related customer ) for a customer.

### Table stats :-

Present volume is 2,00,000 records .

```
Create table
--------------
CREATE TABLE RELATED_TABLE 
( CUS_ID            VARCHAR2(09) ,
  REL_CUS_ID        VARCHAR2(09) ,
  COUNT_OF_REL_CUST NUMBER(12)) ;

Sample data:-
---------------  
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','898196448',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','855115206',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('402758970','850353774',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','691094946',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','404636299',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('898196448','402758970',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','870397045',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','855115206',3);
 INSERT INTO RELATED_TABLE VALUES ('855115206','402758970',3);


CUS_ID     REL_CUS_ID    COUNT_OF_REL_CUST   
402758970  898196448       3                                                          
402758970  855115206       3                                                          
402758970  850353774       3                                     
898196448  691094946       3                                     
898196448  404636299       3                                     
898196448  402758970       3                                            
855115206  870397045       3                                            
855115206  855115206       3                                            
855115206  402758970       3

OUTPUT:-
--------------------

402758970  898196448
402758970  855115206
402758970  850353774
402758970  691094946
402758970  404636299
402758970  870397045
402758970  855115206
```

### EDIT

i had used some thing like this but got an error saying loop in user data

```
select * from
  (select connect_by_root(cus_id) cus_id, rel_cus_id
     from RELATED_TABLE
       start with rel_cus_id is not null
       connect by prior cus_id = rel_cus_id)
  where cus_id <> rel_cus_id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hierarchical queries in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704472/hierarchical-queries-in-oracle)

Comment: i had used some thing like this but got an error saying loop in user data
select * from (
   select connect_by_root(cus_id) cus_id, rel_cus_id
   from RELATED_TABLE
   start with rel_cus_id is not null
   connect by prior cus_id = rel_cus_id)
where cus_id <> rel_cus_id ;

Comment: Please do not include additional information in comments, as people are far less likely to notice it. Instead, edit your question (the `edit` button is positioned underneath the tags) and include the new information in the question itself. I've done it for your this time.

Answer (score 0):

The below query returns your expected result:

```
 with tree ( cust_id, child_id, path, exist) as
 (select cus_id ,
         rel_cus_id ,
         cus_id || ',' || rel_cus_id,
         0
   from  RELATED_TABLE 
  where cus_id = '402758970'
  union all
   select t.cust_id,
          rt.rel_cus_id,
          t.path || ',' || rt.rel_cus_id,
          instr(t.path, rt.cus_id)
   from tree t
   join related_table rt
    on t.child_id = rt.cus_id and
        t.exist = 0 )
    select distinct cust_id, child_id from tree
```

I used there `exist` that cuts cycles. The distinct was used to remove duplication that were received by different paths.

Sample in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff7a0/1/0)

In case you don't want to show `402758970 -> 402758970` relation use the below:

```
 with tree ( cust_id, child_id, path) as
 (select cus_id ,
         rel_cus_id ,
         cus_id || ',' || rel_cus_id
   from  RELATED_TABLE 
  where cus_id = '402758970'
  union all
   select t.cust_id,
          rt.rel_cus_id,
          t.path || ',' || rt.rel_cus_id
   from tree t
   join related_table rt
    on t.child_id = rt.cus_id and
          instr(t.path, rt.rel_cus_id) = 0 )
    select distinct cust_id, child_id from tree
```

Comment: @dcieslak- today i had executed the SQL against a table which had 0.2 million records the SQL ran for around 30 minutes with out any record fetched. can you please let me know how to increase the performance of this SQL i wanted to learn how to tune a SQL to perform better.

Comment: @mikey Add index on RELATED_TABLE on columns that are used in the join. `CREATE INDEX idx_RELATED_TABLE_01 on RELATED_TABLE (cus_id, rel_cus_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the output using below SQL

```
SQL> SELECT  DISTINCT '402758970' CUS_ID,
  2                   REL_CUS_ID
  3    FROM  RELATED_TABLE
  4    START WITH CUS_ID = '402758970'
  5    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR REL_CUS_ID = CUS_ID
  6  /

CUS_ID    REL_CUS_ID
--------- ---------
402758970 898196448
402758970 691094946
402758970 870397045
402758970 402758970
402758970 404636299
402758970 850353774
402758970 855115206
```